# Spring schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document /org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd

Tags: spring, schema, javabeans

When I use spring , spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE

```
  WARN  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: Please, post the xml that's having this issue. Only the schemas part at the top.

Comment: Have you solved the error?